# Ajax posting Json array is not retrieved by controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

**Javascript**

```
var poItemData = JSON.stringify(grid.getAll());
        poItemData = JSON.stringify({ 'poItemData': poItemData });
        alert(poItemData.toString());
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdate2", "PurchaseOrder")",
            data: poItemData,
            success: function () {
                alert("Ok");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("!Ok");
            }
        });
```

**Posted Json**

```
{"poItemData":"[{"id":3,"itemName":"Item 1","itemId":1,"poId":2,"quantity":100,"averageCost":100,"recordStatus":"O"},{"id":4,"itemName":"Item 2","itemId":2,"poId":2,"quantity":1000,"averageCost":10,"recordStatus":"O"}]"}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult CreateOrUpdate2(List<PurchaseOrderItemList> poItemData)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Entity

```
public class PurchaseOrderItemList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int POId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageCost { get; set; }
    public string RecordStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The posted Json is not retrieved by controller. I wanted to retrieve the posted result as list. Please help to resolve

My project is running on .net core 1.0.0 framework.

Comment: Try poItemData = JSON.stringify( poItemData);

Comment: Your supplied JSON is not valid. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: That JSON is one big quoting error.  Are you posting it as actual JSON, or as a *string*?  If the latter, then wouldn't the controller be expecting a string as well?  Either way, whether the model binder deserializes the JSON or whether you manually deserialize it from a string in your controller, you'll need to start with valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already posted, try with

```
formatedData = JSON.stringify(poItemData);
...
data: formatedData,
```

And I would change the method signature to

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateOrUpdate2(PurchaseOrderItemList[] poItemData)
```

Because Im not sure if u can directly receive a List instance in the method

Comment: Thank you all, Json had an issue after stringing. fixed it thank you. by the way I have resolved the posing issue using below code

var poItemData = grid.getAll();
            $.ajax({ url: actionUrl, data: { poHeaderData: formData, poItemData: poItemData }, method: 'POST' })
                        .done(function () {
                            //grid.reload();
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            alert('Failed to delete the record, please try again later.');
                        });